# What is the best way to debug production error templates?

Tags: symfony, twig

I am trying to create pretty error pages for my application by following this [cookbook article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html). Sometimes a bug slips in, which causes the application to return a single line: `503 Service Unavailable`. It would make my life a whole lot easier if only I could see the underlying error or exception thrown. Switching over to the development environment doesn't help either as the error templates are only used in production.

I figured out that I needed to add `TwigBundle` to assetic's configuration to use javascript and css assets. Problems like this are really hard to debug in the production environment.

Setting the debug mode to `true` in my front controller doesn't help, since production error templates get replaced by development templates.

**EDIT**

Thanks to Mike Purcell I managed to retrieve the errors provided. I got

> Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException' in /[snip]/app/cache/prod/appprodUrlMatcher.php:669

Turns out the framework should be handling the exception, but in the case of a possible error inside the error Twig template, it just decides to throw a 503 error.

<s>How do I turn on error reporting for the production environment in a Symfony2 application?</s>

I'm tired of guessing what's wrong and clearing the cache. What is the best way to debug Twig's error templates in production?

Comment: This is exactly why the php error_log file exists.

Comment: @MikePurcell indeed. I'd be happy to have the errors going to `error_log`. Unfortunately the log is empty.

Comment: You can configure your php error log handling via php.ini, specifically the `error_log` entry. http://us3.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log . You can check your current setting by running this via cli: `php -i | fgrep -i error_log`

Comment: @MikePurcell Thanks for the tip. There's no related entries. I grepped through the framework code looking for `error_reporting` and `display_errors`. Found the code suppressing errors and commented it out. Success! I'm getting a  `ResourceNotFoundException` which in turn should trigger rendering the error template, but the exception is not caught.

Comment: I would update your question with the newly found issue as I am sure some Symfonians (v2) will be able to assist you further.

Comment: isnt symfony catching the errors and putting them into app/logs/prod.log? In your config you can even configure your depth of loging. you should look there first before altering the core code.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to see what errors are being thrown in production is to configure Monolog to email the errors too you or alternatively to a file.

Have a look at the Symfony2 Cookbook on emailing logs http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/logging/monolog_email.html

To make the error pages look nicer have a look at this cookbook entry on how to do that http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html

Comment: Emailing errors is insane if you are running a high traffic application.

Comment: Not always insane, but often not advisable. I do this on a heavily used site and only get 0-3 emails a day however everything is heavily unit and functional tested and any exception on the live system is investigated and fixed quickly with a new test. Emailing them tends to mean they get fixed faster unless you have someone actively monitoring the logs 24x7

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have updated my question and unfortunately this is not a viable method for development. I am indeed following the cookbook entry and simple stuff work great, but a tad more sophisticated templates produce errors that cannot be debugged properly.

Answer (score 0):

There are open source tools specifically built for error reporting like [Sentry](https://getsentry.com/welcome/), which has a [native Symfony client](https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/clients/php/integrations/symfony2/?_ga=1.13843127.1035364749.1447199367).

disclaimer: I work for Sentry